# How to prove this very interesting matrix identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices

This is a very interesting identity but I don't know how to prove this, 
note that $$A_1,\ldots,A_J,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$$
and $m$ is the number of block diagonal in $\mathbf{A}$ ,so consider
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 & \ldots &A_J & & & & \\
& & & \ddots \\
& & & & A_1 & A_2 & \ldots & A_J
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{nm\times (Jnm)}$$
$$
\mathbf{B} = \begin{bmatrix}
B & & \\
& \ddots & \\
& & B 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(Jnm)\times (Jnm)}$$
$$
\mathbf{A}^\prime = 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
A_1 & &  & & A_2 & & & & \ldots & & & & A_J\\
& A_1 & & & & A_2 & & & & \ldots & & & & A_J\\
& & \ddots &  & & & \ddots & & & & \ldots & & & & \ddots \\
& & & A_1 & & & & A_2 & & & & \ldots & & & & A_J   
\end{smallmatrix}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{mn\times (Jmn)}$$

$$
\mathbf{B}^\prime =
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}B \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}  & &  & & \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ B\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}  & & & & \ldots & & & & \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ B \\ \end{bmatrix}\\
& \begin{bmatrix}B \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}  & & & & \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ B\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} & & & & \ldots & & & & \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ B \\ \end{bmatrix}\\
& & \ddots &  & & & \ddots & & & & \ldots & & & & \ddots \\
& & & \begin{bmatrix}B \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}  & & & & \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ B\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} & & & & \ldots & & & & \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ B \\ \end{bmatrix}   
\end{smallmatrix}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{Jmn\times (Jmn)}$$

It seems to be true that 
$$\mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{A^\prime B^\prime}$$

### what I guess might work

From $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{A}^\prime$ it is a column permutation $\mathbf{C}$, while explicitly find its inverse should give us $$\mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{A CC^{-1} B}= \mathbf{A^\prime B^\prime}$$

But it seems to me, very difficult to write down the $\mathbf{C}$

### Update:

It seems that C can be written but well, I can show it is correct by *hand-waving* way to write it down then...

Comment: An aside: your matrices need a bit of condensing. Hard to tell what is going on in $B,$ and $B'$ goes off my screen completely. I'm not sure which options MathJax supports for doing this though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the $nmJ\times nmJ$ matrix with $m\times J$ blocks of size $nJ\times nm$ with blocks labeled $P_{i,j}$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,\ldots,J$.

Define $P_{i,j}$ to be the block matrix of $J\times J$ blocks of size $n\times n$ where the $j,i$ block is the $n\times n$ identity and all other entries are zero.

Note that each row and column of $P$ has exactly one 1. Therefore $P$ is a permutation. Moreover $A' = AP$ and $B' = P^TB$ so that $A'B' = APP^TB = AB$.

For instance, here is $P$ when $J=3$, $m=4$
$$
P = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc|cccc}
I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_n  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\right]
$$

However, you still need to verify that $A' = AP$ and $B' = P^TA$ which requires just as much work as directly verifying that $AB = A'B'$. Note that you can just assume that $I_n = 1$ and $A_i = a_i$ since block matrix rules are the same as regular matrix rules.

Answer (score 1):

It seems helpful to rewrite these matrices using [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  In particular, we have
$$
\mathbf A = I_m \otimes \pmatrix{A_1 & \cdots & A_J} = \sum_{k=1}^J I_m \otimes e_k^T \otimes A_k\\
\mathbf B = I_{Jm} \otimes B = I_m \otimes I_J \otimes B \\
\mathbf A' = \pmatrix{I_m \otimes A_1 & \cdots & I_m \otimes A_J} = \sum_{k=1}^J e_k^T \otimes I_m \otimes A_k\\
\mathbf B' = \pmatrix{I_m \otimes e_1 \otimes B & \cdots & I_m \otimes e_J \otimes B}
= \sum_{k=1}^J e_k^T \otimes I_m \otimes e_k \otimes B
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, and $e_i$ is the $i$th column of the identity matrix (in this case, of the size $J$ identity matrix).

With all that said, we can now use the properties of the Kronecker product to compute
$$
\mathbf {AB} = [\sum_{k=1}^J I_m \otimes e_k^T \otimes A_k][I_m \otimes I_J \otimes B]\\
= \sum_{k=1}^JI_m \otimes e_k^T \otimes (A_kB)\\
= I_m \otimes \pmatrix{A_1B & \cdots & A_JB}
$$
Unfortunately, I'm having trouble performing a similar computation on the product $\mathbf{A'B'}$.  However, I still think you will find this useful.

---

The column permutation that takes us from $\mathbf A$ to $\mathbf A'$ can be nicely described by
$$
(e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(J)} \otimes e_k^{(n)})^TC = (e_i^{(J)} \otimes e_j^{(m)} \otimes e_k^{(n)})^T
$$ 
and in fact, we can deduce that $C = C^{-1}$.  With that in mind, it seems that you have miscalculated $\mathbf B'$.  We should have
$$
\mathbf B' = C \mathbf B = \mathbf B
$$
So you should find that $\mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{A'B}$.

Comment: thanks! but isn't column permutation matrix C should have its inverse equals its transpose? so $C^{-1} = C^\top$?

Comment: @ArtificiallyIntelligence right, so $C$ as it turns out is a symmetric matrix